# How do I properly apply functions in 'if-statement' to a specific game object tag in C# & Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement, 3d

What I am attempting to do is apply the Debugger script to show the message "we hit an obstacle" when my player makes a collision with the white cube, which is tagged as an obstacle.

The problem is: when my player makes contact with the floor/plane it shows "we hit an obstacle" and then the player proceeds to collide with the actual obstacle and it repeats the message.

The white cube is tagged as "obstacle" in the inspector, the player is tagged as "player", and the plane which the game is played on is tagged as "floor."

In my source function, I've made sure to only include the tag labeled as "obstacle" and the only thing in my scene that is tagged as such is my obstacle.

Every time my player makes contact with the floor or any other game object that isn't tagged, it still shows the message.

How do I fix this to only apply this function to a specific tag in unity?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {
        
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle") {
            Debug.Log("We hit an obstacle");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the scene I am trying to apply the code to, you can see in console it reads as two messages when there is only supposed to be one, indicating that my function is applying to more than one game object rather than my intended object. You can also see in the top left in the inspector, the Obstacle is tagged as obstacle.

[image]

Comment: Try to Debug.Log() for gameObject.name. This way you can be sure if one of the collision firing from the floor.

Comment: As @SeLeCtRa suggests: Make it `Debug.Log($"We hit an obstacle called {collisionInfo.gameObject.name}", collisionInfo.gameObject);` this way you a) see the name of the actual object you collide with and b) can click once on the debug in the console and it will highlight the according object in your scene hierarchy

Comment: Alternatively it is also possible that you actually only hit **one** object as intended but you get the log from two different instances of your script. So if the first try prints the same for both logs and refers to the same hit object then change it to `Debug.Log($"{name} hit an obstacle called {collisionInfo.gameObject.name}", this);` which would now additionally print out the name of the object this script is attached to and if you click it once it highlights the object that caused the log instead

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you usually don't compare tags like strings.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        
}
```

Taken from the docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html

In your case it is `collisionInfo.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle")`. You need the gameobject of the collider which holds the tag.

You should also consider putting your tag names into a static class as static strings from where you can access them and with that eliminate the possibility of typos.

```
public static class TagNames
{
     public static string Obstacle = "Obstacle";
     public static string Player = "Player";
}
```

And use them like that `collisionInfo.collider.gameObject.CompareTag(TagNames.Obstacle)`.

Comment: That's a good advices. But your answer is not a solution and not intented to be one.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to do:

```
if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
{
    Debug.Log("We hit an obstacle");
}
```

Instead of gameObject, use collider. Also I don't know if you had a semi-colon after the if statement, or if it's just a formatting error, but there's no need for that either.

Comment: _there's no need for that either_ It is probably the problem and it is wrong, because the body block will always be executed. With the semicolon the `if` statement does nothing.

Comment: I though it was just copy paste problem with StackOverflow

Comment: Note that [`Collision.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html) `The GameObject whose collider you are colliding with.` and [`Collision.collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-collider.html) `The Collider we hit` .. from the [`Component` source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.cs): `public string tag { get { return gameObject.tag; } set { gameObject.tag = value; } }` => Makes absolutely no difference (except yours might be a millisecond faster ^^)